# Search an array by the first letters in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array:

```
dictionary = [ 
  'abnormal',
  'arm-wrestling',
  'absolute',
  'airplane',
  'airport',
  'amazing',
  'apple',
  'ball'
]
```

How can I search the first five matches, or less if there are not five matches, by their first letters?

```
input = "a"
match = dictionary.select { |a| a.match(input) }
puts match
```

`match` returns

```
["abnormal", "arm-wrestling", "absolute", "airplane", "airport", "amazing", "apple", "ball"]
```

but I need it to return

```
["abnormal", "arm-wrestling", "absolute", "airplane", "airport"]
```

and do not return words like `["ball"]` just because it contains "a".

Comment: Is your dictionary already sorted?

Comment: dictionary should stay as it is. It can't be changed. It should return all results in the order given in the dictionary, even if they're not always alphabetical.

Comment: I don't want to change your array, but _if_ your array is sorted, you could use `bsearch_index` to find the first word's index instead of traversing the entire array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need first five words that starts with `'a'`.

You can use [String#`start_with?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-start_with-3F):

```
dictionary.select { |word| word.start_with?('a') }.first(5)
```

For better performance you can `lazy` select these five words. It will especially make sense if the collection you are performing search on is growing bigger:

```
dictionary.lazy.select { |word| word.start_with?('a') }.first(5)
```

For case insensitive selection:

```
dictionary.lazy.select { |word| word.start_with?('a', 'A') }.first(5)
```

Comment: You can add a `.lazy` before `.select` to stop traversing the array after 5 matches have been found.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko this is a very accurate answer, thanks.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Can I make a search not case-sensitive? For example, the word "Hello" starts with "h" letter, but it does not find this word because first "Hello" letter is upcase.

Comment: @KirillZhuravlov sure, `dictionary.select {|a| a[0] =~ /a/i}.first(5)`

Comment: `%w|a A|.include? a[0]`

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Can I use variable instead of "a"?  var = "a"

Comment: `word.start_with?('a', 'A')` or `word.downcase.start_with?('a')`. The latter also works with a variable.

Comment: Don't use a regex if at all possible. They slow down things, especially when you don't use an anchor in the pattern. `lazy` isn't necessary faster.

Answer (score 3):

```
▶ dictionary.group_by { |w| w[0] }
#⇒ {
#    "a" => [
#        [0] "abnormal",
#        [1] "arm-wrestling",
#        [2] "absolute",
#        [3] "airplane",
#        [4] "airport",
#        [5] "amazing",
#        [6] "apple"
#    ],
#    "b" => [
#        [0] "ball"
#    ]
# }
```

`dictionary.group_by { |w| w[0] }['a'].take(5)` will return the array requested.

or, using `grep`:

```
dictionary.grep(/\Aa/).take(5)
```

or, lazy:

```
dictionary.lazy.grep(/\Aa/).first(5)
```

Comment: I think OP looks for first 5 occurrences of words starting with "a" (at least this is how I understand `How can I search first 5 matches by first letters?`)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are lots of answers being tossed out with no regard to processing speed. This doesn't attempt to measure returning the first five words, only determining whether words begin with an `'a'`:

```
words = %w[
  aback
  agonizing
  bell
  bubble
  dear
  lackadaisical
  mouth
  nonstop
  rinse
  steel
  stroke
]

var = 'a'

require 'fruity'
```

This compares all:

```
var = 'a'
compare do
  starts_with { words.select { |w| w.start_with?('a') } }
  downcase { words.select { |w| w.downcase.start_with?('a') } }
  regexp { words.select { |w| w[0] =~ /a/i } }
  mudasobwa1 { words.select { |a| %w|a A|.include? a[0] } }
  mudasobwa2 { words.group_by { |w| w[0] }['a'] }
  mudasobwa3 { words.grep(/\Aa/).to_a }
  mudasobwa4 { words.lazy.grep(/\Aa/).to_a }
  stefan { words.select { |word| word.start_with?('a', 'A') } }
  andrey_deinko { words.select { |a| a[0] =~ /#{var}/ }}
  andrey_deinko2 { words.lazy.select { |word| word.start_with?('a') }.to_a }
end

# >> Running each test 2048 times. Test will take about 4 seconds.
# >> starts_with is similar to stefan
# >> stefan is similar to downcase
# >> downcase is faster than mudasobwa1 by 2x ± 0.1
# >> mudasobwa1 is similar to mudasobwa3
# >> mudasobwa3 is similar to regexp
# >> regexp is similar to mudasobwa2
# >> mudasobwa2 is similar to andrey_deinko2
# >> andrey_deinko2 is similar to mudasobwa4
# >> mudasobwa4 is faster than andrey_deinko by 4x ± 1.0
```

To try to help the `lazy` methods, I expanded the size of the `words` array by 1000:

```
words = (%w[
  aback
  agonizing
  bell
  bubble
  dear
  lackadaisical
  mouth
  nonstop
  rinse
  steel
  stroke
] * 1000).shuffle
```

Rerunning shows:

```
# >> Running each test 2 times. Test will take about 4 seconds.
# >> starts_with is similar to stefan
# >> stefan is similar to andrey_deinko2
# >> andrey_deinko2 is similar to downcase
# >> downcase is similar to mudasobwa2
# >> mudasobwa2 is similar to mudasobwa1
# >> mudasobwa1 is similar to mudasobwa3
# >> mudasobwa3 is similar to mudasobwa4
# >> mudasobwa4 is similar to regexp
# >> regexp is faster than andrey_deinko by 9x ± 1.0
```

There's a serious speed price to pay with regex so learn to use anchors. I won't go into it here but there are questions and answers on SO showing the differences so search for them.

Keep it simple. Take advantage of the built-in methods designed for the purpose.

Comment: The point of the `lazy` methods (at least in this situation) is _specifically_ that they improve performance when you're pulling the first few items from a large list. Without `lazy`, `select` for example will process the whole list when it really could have stopped after five. But if you ignore the 'I only want the first five' requirement, then of course `lazy` doesn't add anything.